# how to use the package "clearpath_kinect"

Tags: ros, clearpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the package "clearpath_kinect" subscribe to the topic "idfloor_in" with the message type "sensor_msgs/PointCloud2",and I run the node "openni_node" which has the same message type as the topic "idfloor_in",so I changed "idfloor_in" to "openni_node" so that they can connect with each other.And then the window running the node ClearpathDemoExplore shows :
BAD INITIALIZATION, NORMAL FAILED, TRY AGAIN
Do I have mistakes when using the package "clearpath_kinect"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33490/how-to-use-the-package-%22clearpath_kinect%22/) by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That particular demo package automatically calibrates the position and orientation of the Kinect relative to the ground. Due to this, it requires you to have a reasonable amount of flat ground within the field of view of the Kinect on startup for the initialization to succeed. How do you have the Kinect positioned with respect to the ground?

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2012-05-13**:
Thank you.I set the Kinect in the wrong way.But now it has a warning:Iteration of vision loop took **** seconds (max is 0.100000),which is larger than 0.100000.And the data on the topic idfloor_out_vel is a set value: tw.linear.x =0,  tw.angular.z =-0.3. Can you tell me why?

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-05-14**:
What platform are you using this with? There's also a "height from floor" parameter.

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2012-05-14**:
The platform I am using is just a PC computer.And I have adjusted all the parameter.

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-05-14**:
Sorry, I meant what robot are you using it with?

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2012-05-14**:
I am using it with a robot which we make by ourselves.